# Car under the dealer's warranty

Tags: car, car-insurance, ohio

I just bought a car from a dealer and according to the law, they have provided a 3-month warranty to pay half a price for the repairs in case the car breaks.

The car broke down and I need to have it fixed. My worry is that they might charge me much higher and earn money from me again since they can say the cost is much higher. And since they provide the labor they won't end up paying anything. 
What are my options? This law seems ridiculous. Is there something I'm missing? Does the dealership have some limit they can charge me?

I'm in OH, USA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not get an estimate at few different shops?  Some that honor the warranty and others that don't.  Then you can make a math based decision on where to have the car fixed.

While your fear is reasonable, information is a remedy.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I'm going to take the car to a different shop. The problem is that some charge fees for the estimate.